# Alert user when updating child record based on other related child records

Tags: apex, list

I am trying to display an error when updating a child record. Here's my scenario
Parent Bank__c
Child Branch__c
Relationship field on child BankId__c
Updating field on child checkbox Primary_Branch__c

My requirement is only one child Branch can be a primary branch for a Bank, if a user tries to update another branch as primary branch where there is an existing branch it should display an alert stating that there is an existing bank which is primary.

```
public static string validatePrimarybranch(String branchId, String bankId){
    List<branch__c> branchList = new List<branch__c>();
    branchList  = [SELECT Primary_branch__c FROM branch__c WHERE bankId__c =: bankId];
    String displayString = '';
    --
    --
    return displayString;
}
```

debug Log:

```
branchlist: (branch__c:{Primary_branch__c=true, Id=a0L2g0000006y6dTREY}, branch__c:{Primary_branch__c=false, Id=a0L2g0000006y6dTREY})
```

I am getting list of branches with data, but how can I just grab that primary branch data from that list and add it to string, so that I can display an error when that field is being updated.

Any suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is getting back data that you don't need. If all you want is the details of the one primary branch, or the information that there is no primary branch, filter your query by that field:

```
branchList  = [SELECT Name FROM branch__c WHERE bankId__c =: bankId WHERE Primary_branch__c = true];
```

Then you can just check `branchList.size()` - if it's 0, there's no primary branch; if it's nonzero, the data for the primary branch is located in `branchList[0]`, e.g., `branchList[0].Name`.

Comment: oh yea, I did not think in that way.. It worked!! 
Thanks a lot David!